# SQL-Server is ignoring my COLLATION when I'm using LIKE operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation, sql-like

I'm working with Spanish database so when I'm looking for and "aeiou" I can also get "áéíóú" or "AEIOU" or "ÁÉÍÓÚ", in a where clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE stringData like '%perez%'
```

I'm expencting:

```
* perez
* PEREZ
* Pérez
* PÉREZ
```

So I changed my database to collation: Modern_Spanish_CI_AI

And I get only:

```
* perez
* PEREZ
```

But if I do:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE stringData like '%perez%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI
```

I get all results OK, so my question is, why if my database is COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI I have to set the same collation to my query???

I'm using SQL-Server 2008

Comment: The `stringdata` column may have a different collation to the database

Comment: There is no easy way, especially if constraints are in the way. Search on Google for "SQL server change collation". It will give you nightmares.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the collation of the table COLUMN itself.

```
select collation_name, *
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('tblname')
  and name = 'stringdata';
```

If you're lucky it is as easy as (example)

```
alter table tblname alter column stringdata varchar(20) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

But if you have constraints and/or schema bound references, it can get complicated.
It can be very difficult to work with a database with mixed collations, so you may want to re-collate all the table columns.

Comment: You are right, can I change the collation to all my data structure at once?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `COLLATE`, eg.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE strData COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI = 'perez' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

both sides must have the same collation.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb5bb/9)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using LIKE*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb5bb/11)

Others:

- [Selecting a SQL Server Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx)

Comment: Thank you is an excelent example, but what I want is not to use the "COLLATE" operator in the select I want to take the default.