# why no results are displayed when searching a value in Hebrew string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, hebrew

this is my sql query

```
SELECT [ID] ,[Caption] FROM  [Dictionary] where Caption like 'חי%'
```

The information exists in my table, but is not displayed.

When i change the hebrew word (חי) to english word it works fine.

I have Microsoft sql 2008..(if it matters..)
what am i missing here?

Comment: have you tried doing '%חי%' ? mind both of the percentages

Comment: What collation does your database use?

Comment: yep, i tried '%חי' and '%חי%' and 'חי%' nothing changed

Comment: Check if COLLATION is the same: [SQL-Server is ignoring my COLLATION when I'm using LIKE operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660346/sql-server-is-ignoring-my-collation-when-im-using-like-operator)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21073114/50447

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the N prefix so the string literal is interpreted as unicode not char under the code page of whatever your database's default collation is

Try this

```
SELECT [ID] ,[Caption] FROM  [Dictionary] where Cast(Caption AS Nvarchar(max))like N'חי%'
```